# Understanding output of slicing operation

Tags: python, list, slice

I have a `list` object which looks as below:

```
lst = [50,34,98,8,10]
```

The output for the statement `print(lst[:5:-2])` is coming as blank `[]`

My understanding is that `print(lst[:5:-2])` translates to `print(lst[-1:5:-2])`

This means:

- start from index -1  # this corresponds to value 10
- stop at index 4  # this corresponds to value 10
- perform increment of -2

As `start` and `stop` are pointing to `10` so I am expecting the output to be `10` here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://tutorial.eyehunts.com/python/start-stop-step-python-slice-parameters/

Comment: The syntax is `lst[start:stop:step]` (I didn't really understand what increment was)

Comment: Start at index `-1` (i.e. 4). Stop before reaching index 5. There are no elements between 4 and 5 going backwards (just like there are no indices between 1 and 0, going forwards, which is why `lst[1:0]` returns empty). The first range that would include an element is `lst[:3:-2]` (start at 4, stop before 3, 4 is before 3 going backwards, thus `lst[4]` gets included).

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to understand python slicing syntax is to think about it as such: `slice[start:stop:step]`.

What this means is that your starting point is `start`, here that's index `-1` since the starting position for a negative step is `-1`. It stops at `stop`, here that's the 4th element. When using a step of `-2` the first iteration will be the 4th element. Thus nothing is returned since you've already arrived at your stop condition.

Answer (score 0):

So the documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice), and additional explanation [here](https://tutorial.eyehunts.com/python/start-stop-step-python-slice-parameters/). And another additional explanation you can read [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-slicing/).
On your case that syntax is same as

```
print(lst[-1:5:-2])
```

OR

```
print(lst[-1:-1:-2])
```

- Note this is because python also can use negative indexing, and last item is indexed as `-1`... till the first item indexed as `-len(list)`. So index `5` is same as `-1`
- Also the negative step indicates that the starting point is the last item of list or index `-1`

So what it's done:

- Start from index `-1` # this corresponds to value `10`
- Stop at index `-1` # this correspond to value `10`
- Using `-2` as step

because the step is `-2` and the start is already smaller than or same with stop (`start <= stop`) the slice result to empty because nothing taken from the `list`.

for example how to use `negative step`, you can run

```
print(lst[5:0:-2])
```

same as

```
print(lst[-1:-5:-2])
```

that's will return `[10, 98]`

```
print(lst[5::-2])
```

same as

```
print(lst[-1:-6:-2])
```

that's will return `[10, 98, 50]`

You can still use `-len(list)-1` for indexing to inclusive the first item that contains in index `-len(list)`.

Comment: My understanding is that when we have a negative step then the `start` position is `-1` and not `0`. Please correct

Comment: If that's the case, why does `lst[:5:-1]` return `[]` but `lst[:3:-1]` return `[10]` ?

Comment: @Underoos because in python, there exists negative index too. So I will update the answer. Corresponds to the right meaning of negative step